# CSS animation don't work in IE

Tags: css

I have a problem with CSS animation. Animation works great in IE10 (and Chrome, Mozilla, Safari), but doesn't work in IE9 (and also IE edge).

This is my CSS:

```
.tossing07{
-webkit-animation-name: tossing07;  
animation-name: tossing07;

-webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
animation-duration: 0.3s;   

-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes tossing07 {
0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);  
}
50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);  
}               
}

@keyframes tossing07 {
0% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);  
}
50% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
100% {
    transform: rotate(-25deg);  
    }                       
}
```

Comment: try prefixing with `-ms-`

Comment: @AndyHolmes Thanks, but it's still the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal, animation work since Ie10 look at [can i use page](http://caniuse.com/css-animation), sorry

Answer (score 1):

CSS animation is not supported for IE9 or earlier. Thats why your css animation is not working. Even vendor prefixing would not work.